# serverless deploy : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enum') at new ServerlessPlugin

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, bref

I am getting error in laravel when i am running command:
serverless deploy

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enum')
> at new ServerlessPlugin (/home/softuvo/.local/share/Trash/files/laravel-bref/laravel-

how to solve this issue?

Comment: Provide screenshot of error please :)